# The issue about the deferred dynamic initialization

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider the example in the section [basic.start.dynamic](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.start.dynamic#4), that is:

```cpp
// - File 1 -
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
B b;
A::A(){
  b.Use();  //#1
}

// - File 2 -
#include "a.h"
A a;

// - File 3 -
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
extern A a;
extern B b;

int main() {
  a.Use();  //#2
  b.Use();
}
```

The comments follow the example  are:

> If, however, a is initialized at some point after the first statement of main, b will be **initialized prior to its use in A​::​A**.

I can't understand why `b` is guaranteed initialized prior to its use in A​::​A when a is initialized at some point after the first statement of main.  According to what the rule says:

[basic.start.dynamic#4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.start.dynamic#4)

> It is implementation-defined whether the dynamic initialization of a non-local non-inline variable with static storage duration is sequenced before the first statement of main or is deferred. **If it is deferred, it strongly happens before any non-initialization odr-use of any non-inline function or non-inline variable defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized.**

[basic.start.dynamic#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.start.dynamic#3)

> A non-initialization odr-use is an odr-use ([basic.def.odr]) **not caused directly or indirectly by the initialization of a non-local static or thread storage duration variable**.

What I can understand is that, when the initialization is deferred, the variable `a` should be initialized prior to the odr-use(non-initialization odr-use) of the variable `a` which is at the place marked with `#2`. However what I can't understand is that, the comment says that **b will be initialized prior to its use in A​::​A**. IIUC, the invocation of function `A::A` is as a part of initialization of the variable `a`, hence the odr-use of the variable `b` at `#1` is not a non-initialization odr-use due to it is caused directly or indirectly by the initialization of a non-local static or thread storage duration variable. I think it only can say that the variable `b` is guaranteed to be initialized prior to `#2`, why the comment says that b will be **initialized prior to its use in A​::​A**? How to interpret this example?

Comment: And why does the "not caused directly or indirectly by the initialization of a non-local static storage duration variable" exception exist at all? In order to avoid addressing circular initialization problems?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I think this sentence is used to limit the cases of odr-use, namely, what kind of odr-use can trigger the occurrence of these dynamic initializations that were deferred. And go back to my question, the odr-use of `b` at `#1` is not the exception which the sentence says, hence it shouldn't trigger the occurence of the dynamic initlaization. however the comment says that it trigger the initialization of `b`, I just don't know why it says that.

Comment: We are in agreement; I was wondering about the reason this restriction was put in the standard.

Comment: Any particular reason for the c++17 tag? Besides, I don't think the text you're quoting has changed in a while.

Comment: @cigien There's no special reason, just from c++17 to c++20, the corresponding texts are all the same. merely, these links I cited in this question is taken from c++17, hence I use the `c++17` tag.

Comment: Ok, it's not a big deal, but for future readers, the tag might indicate that there is something here that *may* have changed since c++17. Since that's not the case, I think the language version that you cite is incidental, and the tag should be removed.

Comment: @cigien Well, I have removed the `c++17` tag. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Part of the answer is that why/when the initialization is evaluated can't be what is meant by "odr-use caused indirectly by the initialization", because `A::A()` contains an odr-use of `b` even if `A::A()` is never invoked at all. That is, odr-use is a semantic property of a name in static analysis, not a property of an execution of the virtual machine. But that leaves the question of what it *does* mean.

Comment: ... Maybe just an odr-use in a subexpression of an initializer for dynamic initialization? Something related to template implicit instantiation?

Comment: @aschepler The odr-use of `A::A()` is caused directly by the initialization of `a` when `A::A()` is selected, hence the odr-use of `b` within `A::A()` is caused indirectly by the initialization of `a`. Because the comment that says the case which is not deferred indicates that, that is "In particular, if a is initialized before main is entered, it is not guaranteed that b will be initialized before it is odr-used by the initialization of a, that is, before A​::​A is called."

Comment: Oh, right. And "sequenced before" and "strongly happens before" mean we're definitely talking about an execution. I still think "odr-use" is used strangely here, but I guess we have to take it as meaning an evaluation of a name expression which odr-uses the variable.

Comment: @aschepler  Yes, that's the exactly meaning of the paragraph [basic.start.dynamic#3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.start.dynamic#3)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Evolution of the clause

The (non-normative) example in question dates back as far as the C++98 edition of the Standard, but the (normative) language in the hosting clause was changed in C++17.

C++98:

> #### 3.6.2 Initialization of non-local objects [basic.start.init]
>
> 3 - It is implementation-defined whether or not the dynamic initialization ([cross-references]) of an object of namespace scope is done before the first statement of main. If the initialization is deferred to some point in time after the first statement of main, it shall occur before the first use of any function or object defined in the same translation unit as the object to be initialized. <sup>[footnote regarding side-effects]</sup> [Example follows]

C++03 has the same text. C++11 removes the cross-references and replaces "object of namespace scope" with "non-local variable with static storage duration", "object" with "variable", and "use" with "odr-use", but I would submit that the meaning of the clause is unaltered. C++14 makes no change.

The language was then changed by [P0250R3](http://wg21.link/p0250r3), published and transcribed into the draft Standard in March 2017, just in time to make it into C++17. P0250R3 added the definition of *non-initialization odr-use* and amended the clause to refer to that definition, while also expressing the relation between events in threading-aware terms (*sequenced before*, *strongly happens before* etcetera), and added a note on avoiding deadlock.

Since then, the note on avoiding deadlock has been amended to a *Recommended practice*.

#### Motivation of the wording change

It is fortunate that P0250R3 includes discussion of motivation. In the section **Parallel initialization for sequential programs** we read:

> Currently, we very explicitly allow static constructors to run after the start of main, whether or not other threads are started. This appears to be motivated by the intent to support e.g. lazily loading a dynamic library when a function symbols is referenced, as with RTLD_LAZY on Posix systems. Even if static namespace-scope constructors are run immediately in library loading, the library may be implicitly loaded after the start of main.

And also:

> SG1 generally feels that static namespace-scope constructors should be avoided [...] we decided to restrict such constructors to existing threads, which appears to be consistent with known implementations.

#### Correctness of the example.

I submit that the example is and always has been incorrect.

In C++98 the example is incorrect because the normative wording in that edition of the Standard leads to circularity. Suppose we augment the example to define the constructor `B::B` in the same TU as the definition of `a`:

```
// - File 2 -
#include "a.h"
A a;
B::B() {
   a.Use();
}
```

Now per C++98 the (dynamic) initialization of `a` occurs before the first call to `B::B`, and also the initialization of `b` occurs before the first call to `A::A`. But the initialization of `a` requires a call to `A::A`, and the initialization of `b` requires a call to `B::B`. So we have a circular regress.

The wording change in P0250R3 (changing *odr-use* to *non-initialization odr-use*) breaks this circularity, at the cost of making the example nonsensical. But then it was always broken. This is the [SIOF](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof), which can be avoided via the Construct on First Use idiom or via the use of helper objects such as [`ios_base::Init`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/Init).

#### Implementation practice

I compiled the example (with circularity) into a (Linux, ELF; CentOS 7.8) shared object, loaded into the program after main was entered using `dlopen`. Precisely one of `a` and `b` was odr-used in an uninitialized state, which one dependent on link ordering.

This demonstrates that the change in wording to *non-initialization odr-use* reflects implementation practice. It is unfortunate that the Standard now contains a clearly incorrect example, but since examples and notes are non-normative this is problematic but not fatal.

Comment: If I understand the current standard correctly, as it says, the variable `b` should be initialized at some point before  `a.Use();` rather than at some point before the `b.Use();` within  `A::A()` right? Because the odr-use of `b` within `A::A()` is caused by initialization of the variable `a`.

Comment: However, the standard does not say which is first initialized before `a.Use()`, furthermore, the variable `b` should remain uninitialized within `A::A()` per current standard.

Comment: `a.Use` (which is called from `main`) is a non-initialization odr-use of `a`. The only variable defined in the TU defining `a` is `a` itself, so `a` only is initialized prior to the call to `a.Use` from `main`. The initialization of `a` invokes (is an odr-use of) `A::A` which is defined in the same TU as `b`, but this is not a non-initialization odr-use (since it is caused indirectly by an initialization) so `b` is not required to be initialized prior to the call to `A::A`.

Comment: Yup, this is also my understanding about the example in the current standard. In addition, Isn't the use of the variable `a` itself not an non-initialization odr-use? which obeys the rule: it strongly happens before any non-initialization odr-use of any non-inline function or **non-inline variable** defined in the same translation unit as the variable to be initialized.

Comment: Moreover, I think the function `A::Use` should be `inline function`, Only the definition for `A::Use` is defined in the class will the code obey the odr rule. Hence , the use of `A::Use` can't cause the intialization of `a` due to it's an inline function. So, I think the odr-use of the variable `a` itselft will trigger the initialization of `a`, do you agree?

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding, both of the normative text of the standard and of how the example will behave. `A::Use` must be an inline function (since it is not explicitly defined, and each header is included from multiple TUs) so it is the odr-use of `a` itself that triggers its own initialization.

Comment: @DavisHerring thanks, corrected - I got the timeline muddled up.